# products are not adding in cart after new registeration in android app

Tags: magento-1.9, api, addtocart

$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';

```
require_once $mageFilename;
umask(0);
Mage::app();

    $product_id = $_REQUEST['product_id'];
    $customerid = $_REQUEST['customer_id'];
    $request_qty = $_REQUEST['qty'];
    $select_ship_label = $_REQUEST['select_ship_label'];
    $time_slot = $_REQUEST['time'];
    $pin = $_REQUEST['pin'];
    $city = $_REQUEST['city'];
    $delivery_date = $_REQUEST['date'];

    $size = $_REQUEST['size'];
    $color = $_REQUEST['color'];
    $flavour = $_REQUEST['flavour'];
    $weight = $_REQUEST['weight']; 
    $image = $_REQUEST['image'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
    $eggless_cake = $_REQUEST['eggless'];
    //initialization
    $shipping_info_is_not_parishable = NULL;
    $shipping_info_is_parishable = NULL;
    $flavour_available = 0;
    $weight_available = 0;
    $flavour_option = '';
    $weight_option ='';
    $file= 0;
    $message_on_cake = 0;
    $eggless_cake = 0;
    $config = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $product_id = $config->getId();
    $is_perishable = $config->getData('is_perishable');
/* Configurable product check for add to cart */
    if($config->isConfigurable()){
        $ids=Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                ->getChildrenIds($product_id);          
        $_subproducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addIdFilter($ids)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('color')-> groupByAttribute('color')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('size')-> groupByAttribute('size');

    foreach($_subproducts as $_subproduct){
            $sub_color = $_subproduct->getAttributeText('color');
            $sub_size = $_subproduct->getAttributeText('size');
                if($sub_color == $color && $sub_size == $size){
                    $_sku = $_subproduct[sku];
                    $sub_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_sku);
                    $sub_product_id = $sub_product->getId();
                    $options[215] = $_subproduct[size];
                    $options[92] = $_subproduct[color];
                }
    }
    $stock = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
            ->loadByProduct($sub_product)->getQty();
    }else{
     $stock = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
            ->loadByProduct($config)->getQty();
    }
         /* Configurable product check for add to cart */


        //print_r($options);
        //$ids = $config->getCategoryIds();

            /* Shipping mathod and price */
        $ship_price = 0;

        if($select_ship_label == 'Standard Delivery'){
            $ship_price = 0;
        }elseif($select_ship_label == 'Fixed Time Delivery'){
            $ship_price = 100;
        }elseif($select_ship_label == 'Mid Night Delivery'){
            $ship_price = 149;
        }
        /* Shipping mathod and price */


        /* Custom option add (Flavour and weight)*/
    $options1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getProductOptionCollection($config);

    foreach ($options1 as $option1) {
        //print_r($option1);
        if ($option1->getType() === 'drop_down') {
            $values = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option_value')->getValuesCollection($option1);
            //print_r($values->getData());
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                //if($value->getData('option_id') == 872){
                    if($value->getData('title')== $weight){
                        $weight_available = 1;
                        $weight_option = $value->getData('title');
                        $option_type_id1 = $value->getData('option_type_id');
                        $option_id1 = $value->getData('option_id');
                    //$weight_option[$value->getData('option_id')][]=$value->getData();
                    }
                //}
                //if($value->getData('option_id') == 873){

                    if($value->getData('title')== $flavour){
                        $flavour_available = 1;
                        $flavour_option = $value->getData('title');
                        $option_type_id2 = $value->getData('option_type_id');
                        $option_id2 = $value->getData('option_id');
                        //$flavour_option[$value->getData('option_id')][]=$value->getData();
                    }

                //}
            }

        }
             if ($option1->getType() === 'file') {
                $file = 1;
                $option_file_id = $option1->getData('option_id');
            }
            if ($option1->getType() === 'field') {
                //print_r($option1);
                $message_on_cake = 1;
                $option_message_id = $option1->getData('option_id');
            }   
                if ($option1->getType() === 'checkbox') {
                //print_r($option1);
                $eggless_cake = 1;
                $option_cake_id = $option1->getData('option_id');
                //print_r($option_cake_id);
            }
        }  
        /* Custom option add (Flavour and weight)*/

        /* Custom option add (Pincode, Delivery date, Delivery type)*/   
        if($is_perishable == 1) {
            if($message_on_cake==1){
                $additionalOptions = array(array(
                'code' => 'my_code',
                'label' => 'Pincode',
                'value' => $pin
            ),
                array(
                    'code' => 'delivery_type',
                    'label' => 'Delivery Type',
                    'value' => $select_ship_label.' '.$time_slot.' + '.$ship_price.' Rs.'
                ),
                array(
                    'code' => 'delivery_date',
                    'label' => 'Delivery Date',
                    'value' => $delivery_date
                ), 

            );


            $config->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));
            $shipping_info_is_parishable = array(
                "pincode" => $pin,
                "delivery_date" => $delivery_date,
                "delivery_type" => $select_ship_label,
                "time" => $time_slot,
                "message" => $message,
                "eggless" => $eggless_cake,
            );
            }
            else{
                $additionalOptions = array(array(
                'code' => 'my_code',
                'label' => 'Pincode',
                'value' => $pin
            ),
                array(
                    'code' => 'delivery_type',
                    'label' => 'Delivery Type',
                    'value' => $select_ship_label.' '.$time_slot.' + '.$ship_price.' Rs.'
                ),
                array(
                    'code' => 'delivery_date',
                    'label' => 'Delivery Date',
                    'value' => $delivery_date
                )
            );
            $config->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));
            $shipping_info_is_parishable = array(
                "pincode" => $pin,
                "delivery_date" => $delivery_date,
                "delivery_type" => $select_ship_label,
                "time" => $time_slot,
            );
            }


        }
        else{
            if ($file==1) {
                $additionalOptions = array(array(
                'code' => 'my_code',
                'label' => 'Pincode',
                'value' => $pin
            ),
                array(
                    'code' => 'delivery_type',
                    'label' => 'Delivery Type',
                    'value' => 'Standard Delivery'
                ),
                array(
                    'code' => 'image',
                    'label' => $option1->getData('title'),
                    'value' => $image,
                    'print_value' => $image,
                    'option_id' => $option_file_id,
                    'option_type' => "file",
                    'type' => 'application/octet-stream',
                    'title' => $image,
                    'quote_path' => '../media/'.$image,
                    'order_path' => '../media/'.$image,
                    'quote_path' => $image,
                    'fullpath' => Mage::getBaseDir() .'/'. $image,
                    'secret_key' => substr(md5(file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir() . $image)), 0, 20)),            
            );

                $config->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));

            $shipping_info_is_not_parishable = array(
                "pincode" => $pin,
                "delivery_date" => '5-7 Business Days',
                "delivery_type" =>'Standard Delivery',
                "time" => '',
                "image" => '../media/'.$image,
            );
            }else{
                $additionalOptions = array(array(
                'code' => 'my_code',
                'label' => 'Pincode',
                'value' => $pin
            ),
                array(
                    'code' => 'delivery_type',
                    'label' => 'Delivery Type',
                    'value' => 'Standard Delivery'
                )
            );
            $config->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));
            $shipping_info_is_not_parishable = array(
                "pincode" => $pin,
                "delivery_date" => '',
                "delivery_type" =>'Standard Delivery',
                "time" => '',
            );
            }
        }
        /* Custom option add (Pincode, Delivery date, Delivery type)*/   

        if($request_qty < $stock && $customerid)
        {
            if($sub_product_id){
                $product_id = $sub_product_id ;
            }
            $mPrice = $config->getFinalPrice();

            $qty = $request_qty;
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerid);
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer);
            $quote->setIsActive(1);
            $ID = $quote->getId();
            if($flavour_available==1 && $weight_available==1 && $message_on_cake==1 && $eggless_cake==1){
                $params = array(
                    'product' => $product_id,
                    'super_attribute' => $options,
                    'options'=>array(
                    $option_id1 => $option_type_id1,
                    $option_id2 => $option_type_id2,
                 ),
                    'qty' => $request_qty,
                );

            }else if($flavour_available==1){
                $params = array(
                    'product' => $product_id,
                    'super_attribute' => $options,
                    'options'=>array(
                    $option_id2 => $option_type_id2,
                 ),
                    'qty' => $request_qty,
                );

            }
            else if($weight_available==1){
                $params = array(
                    'product' => $product_id,
                    'super_attribute' => $options,
                    'options'=>array(
                    $option_id1 => $option_type_id1,
                 ),
                    'qty' => $request_qty,
                );

            }
            else if($message_on_cake==1){
                $params = array(
                    'product' => $product_id,
                    'super_attribute' => $options,
                    'options'   =>  array(
                    $option_message_id => $message,
                 ),
                    'qty' => $request_qty,
                );

            }
            else if($eggless_cake==1){
                $params = array(
                    'product' => $product_id,
                    'super_attribute' => $options,
                    'options'   =>  array(
                    $option_eggless_id => $eggless_cake,
                 ),
                    'qty' => $request_qty,
                );

            }
            else{
                $params = array(
                    'product' => $product_id,
                    'super_attribute' => $options,
                    'qty' => $request_qty,          
                );

            }
            if($quote->addProduct($config, new Varien_Object($params)))
            {   
                $quote->collectTotals()->save();
                        if($flavour_available==1){
                            $falvour_option = $flavour_option;
                        }
                        if($weight_available==1){
                            $weight_option = $weight_option;
                        }               
                        if($options){
                            $configurable = array(
                                "size"=>$size,
                                "color"=>$color,
                        );
                        }

                $respose['isSuccess']='true';
                $respose['quote']=$quote->getId();
                $respose['customer_id']=$customerid;
                $respose['product_id']=$product_id;
                $respose['quantity']=$request_qty;
                $respose['flavour']=$falvour_option;
                $respose['weight']=$weight_option;
                $respose['configurable']=$configurable;
                $respose['parishable_shiping']=$shipping_info_is_parishable;
                $respose['non-parishable_shipping']=$shipping_info_is_not_parishable;
                echo json_encode($respose);

            }
        }
        else{
            $respose['isSuccess']='false';
            $respose['error']='unable to add product';
            echo json_encode($respose);
        }
```

Comment: products are not adding with new registration by mobile app once i will login on website then products are adding.

Comment: please check our website www.sendmygift.com/a‌​pi/add_to_cart.php?ad‌​d_to_cart.php?custome‌​r_id=114&product_id=2‌​85&qty=1&pin=560066&s‌​elect_ship_label=Fixe‌​d Time Delivery&time=8:00-9‌​:00&city=Bangalore&da‌​te=31/08/2016&flavour‌​=Strawberry&weight=2 Kg&color=Purple&size‌​=2.8&image=test.jpg&m‌​essage=miss&eggless=e‌​gglesscake –

Answer (score 0):

```
if($quote->addProduct($config, new Varien_Object($params)))
//just need to add the below code after this condition
            {
                    //$quote->collectTotals()->save();
                    $customerObj = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
                    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
                    $quote->assignCustomer($customerObj);
$quote->setStoreId($storeId);
                    $quote->collectTotals();
                    $quote->save();
```